# IF-Then or Find Function w/ Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, find

My apologies if this has already been answered in some form; it’s difficult to come up with the correct wording to do a proper search.

I have been charged with creating some basic reporting for my team and I need to create an “if-then” formula. Essentially, if Column A contains the word “Open Rate,” I want the formula to grab the associated percentage from column B (16.49%) and make an average of all the open rates on another sheet. (16.49% + 14.98% + 14.48% / 3 = 15.31%)

I would simply add all of them but the data set is ridiculously large and always growing. Also, the numbers of rows between data sets are not equal and thus a nice pattern is out of the question.

Comment: I suspect this is a better fit for the MS Office forum....

Comment: http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/ss/if_function_sbs.htm first link in google

Answer (score 0):

excel uses a vb type syntax

=IF(A2<>"open rate",A2,AVERAGE(Sheet2!A:A))

the above formula says if a2 is not equal to open rate, then return a2, else return the average of column A in sheet 2

Comment: Please mark this or both as the answer (green checkmark). thanks.

Comment: I did test it in excel and it is the exact syntax that he needs, he just has to adjust the specific column names etc.  downvote if you like (ie. don't like).

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=AVERAGEIF(Sheet1!A:A,"=Open Rate",Sheet1!B:B)
```

with your first sheet name adjusted to suit, if necessary.

*Edit re supplementary*

Google Doc does not at the moment have a function =AVERAGEIF, however it does have the building blocks for it. Average (as in arithmetic mean) may be calculated as the sum of the values in a dataset divided by the count of all the individual items in the dataset:

```
=sumIF(Sheet1!A:A;"=Open Rate";Sheet1!B:B)/countIF(Sheet1!A:A;"=Open Rate")
```

Google Doc does have the =AVERAGE function and this may be more suitable than the above.

Comment: The above formula worked like a charm within excel but I was not informed we needed this data in Google Docs for sharing purposes. I have been attempting to make a hybrid version with FILTER to no avail. Is there a way to make "  =AVERAGEIF(Sheet1!A:A,"=Open Rate",Sheet1!B:B)  " work in Google Docs? Thanks for the help.